# Making Blast database from FASTA in Python

Tags: python, biopython, fasta, blast

How can I do this? I use Biopython and saw manual already. Of course I can make blastdb from FASTA using "makeblastdb" in standalone NCBI BLAST+, but I want to whole process in one program.

It seems there are two possible solutions.

1. Find a function which perform this job.

> I cannot find this. I've spent whole day.
>
> Run "makeblastdb" in python.
>
> > I input os.system("C:\blast-2.2.25+\bin\makeblastdb.exe") in my python shell, but I couldn't give any parameters.
> >     
> >     How can I solve this?
> >     Thank you for your helping.

Comment: How have you tried to give parameters when calling makeblastdb as a separate process?

Answer (score 2):

This is classic Blast, but I think the idea stays the same. Code is extracted from my application [KimBlast](http://code.google.com/p/lp-csic-uab/source/browse/kblast_cls_setupframe.py?repo=kimblast). I think it is self-explaining:

```
def on_execute_setup(self, evt):
    """on pressing execute button"""
    FORMAT_EXE = os.path.join(self.blastpath, 'bin', 'formatdb')
    fasta = os.path.join(self.dbpath, self.fasta)
    format_filename = self.format_file.rsplit('.', 1)[0] 
    format_filepath = os.path.join(self.dbpath, format_filename)
    format_type = 'T' if self.format_type == 'protein' else 'F' 

    format_cmd = '%s -i %s -p %s -n %s' % (FORMAT_EXE, fasta, 
                                           format_type, format_filepath)
    process = subprocess.Popen(format_cmd,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                shell=False)

    (out, err) = process.communicate()
```